# R: How to avoid overlapping labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a graphic with ggplot2 and some labels are overlapping. I want to show all labels without overlapping. Is that possible? How? I know there is an option "check_overlap" to geom_text where show or not show labels if there is o not an overlapping. But, this is not what I want. I want and need to show all the labels.

My code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=DRTG, y=ORTG)) +
  geom_point(colour = "#000000") + 
  ggtitle("Gráfico Liga DIA: Ratio Ofensivo / Ratio Defensivo (hasta jornada 8)") +
  geom_text(label=rownames(data), colour = "#000000", nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = 1, size = 4, fontface = "bold", check_overlap = F) +
  geom_point(data=pointMedia, aes(x=mediaDRTG, y=mediaORTG, colour="red", size = 1)) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = pointMedia[, "mediaDRTG"], colour = "green") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = pointMedia[, "mediaORTG"], colour = "blue") +
  geom_text(data=pointMedia, aes(x=mediaDRTG, y=mediaORTG, label="Liga DIA"), nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = 1, colour = "red", fontface = "bold") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  geom_abline(intercept =0 , slope = 1, colour = "orange")+ xlim(70,115) + ylim(70,115)
```

And the image with overlapping on some of their labels:

[image]

Comment: Maybe to specify text positions as a vector: `nudge_y=c(1,1,...,0.6,1.2,...)`?

Comment: mmmm sounds interesting ... I'm going to try it!! Because If I can move the label what I want ... Maybe there is no label overlapping!!!

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much Heikki!!!

Comment: check this out too: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/01/avoid-overlapping-labels-in-ggplot2-charts.html

Comment: Another good option Moody_Mudskipper!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: This is a case for the ggrepel package. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html

Comment: Agreed on `ggrepel`. Also, please just ask one question per question.

Comment: Yes, but with ggrepel I can't put an image instead of a label, don't you?

Comment: I think you need to be more precise with your question. Do you want *one* image as label, or do you want to replace *all* labels with images? Also, could you provide a complete example, including the data you are plotting and the kinds of images you would like to use as labels?

Answer (score 3):

Posting as an answer which was previously a comment.

Instead of passing just one constant value for `nudge_y` for `geom_text`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=DRTG, y=ORTG)) +
  geom_text(label=rownames(data), colour = "#000000", 
            nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = 1, size = 4, fontface = "bold", check_overlap = F)
```

... you may pass a full vector, like `my_nudge_y`:

```
my_nudge_y=c(1,1,...,0.6,1.2,...)
ggplot(data, aes(x=DRTG, y=ORTG)) +
  geom_text(label=rownames(data), colour = "#000000", 
  nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = my_nudge_y, size = 4, fontface = "bold", check_overlap = F)
```

which you use to individually tune the string positions.

Generally solving the overlapping is not very easy problem, because already with a relative small number of texts, the plotting area starts to fill with texts.

Comment: Yes, it is a good solution, but please, check the other solutions that give other solutions where they recommend the use of ggrepel library